# Rotating the Canvas impacts TouchEvents

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates

I have a map application using an in-house map engine on Android. I'm working on a rotating Map view that rotates the map based on the phone's orientation using the Sensor Service. All works fine with the exception of dragging the map when the phone is pointing other than North. For example, if the phone is facing West, dragging the Map up still moves the Map to the South versus East as would be expected. I'm assuming translating the canvas is one possible solution but I'm honestly not sure the correct way to do this.

Here is the code I'm using to rotate the Canvas:

```
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    // mHeading is the orientation from the Sensor
    canvas.rotate(-mHeading, origin[X],origin[Y]);


    mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
    super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

What is the best approach to make dragging the map consistent regardless of the phones orientation?  The sensormanager has a "remapcoordinates()" method but it's not clear that this will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trivially get the delta x and delta y between two consecutive move events. To correct these values for your canvas rotation you can use some simple trignometry:

```
void correctPointForRotate(PointF delta, float rotation) {

    // Get the angle of movement (0=up, 90=right, 180=down, 270=left)
    double a = Math.atan2(-delta.x,delta.y); 
    a = Math.toDegrees(a);  // a now ranges -180 to +180
    a += 180;

    // Adjust angle by amount the map is rotated around the center point
    a += rotation;
    a = Math.toRadians(a);

    // Calculate new corrected panning deltas
    double hyp = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    delta.x = (float)(hyp * Math.sin(a));
    delta.y = -(float)(hyp * Math.cos(a));
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks Reuben! What may be trivial to you had me a bit stumped. I'd thought about offsetting the MotionEvent, but wasn't sure how it'd impact the rest of my app.  Well worth the +50. For those that may be trying the same thing, simply alter the MotionEvent like this: event.setLocation(delta.x,delta.y)

Comment: No worries. Glad you corrected it for the Y-axis inversion I accidentally left in there. This code snippet came from my GL library, and all my GL projections have positive Y pointing up, rather than down as in the Canvas APIs.